# Is Sequelize model.build(req.body) safe for injections?

Tags: node.js, code-injection, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize (a node.js ORM) and wondering if the following code is safe:

```
var models = require('../models');
var router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
  models.Account
    .create(req.body)       // <-- THIS IS WHAT MY QUESTION IS ABOUT, IS THIS SAFE?
    .then(function(result){
      res.status(200)
        .send(result)
        .end();
    }).catch(next);
});
```

If you are using this, could this be unsafe in some way?
The other solution would be:

```
var models = require('../models');
var router = require('express').Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
  models.Account
    .create({
      username:    req.body.username, // <-- THIS IS MORE VERBOSE BUT PROBABLY SAFER?
      accountname: req.body.accountname,
      level:       req.body.level
    })
    .then(function(result){
      res.status(200)
        .send(result)
        .end();
    }).catch(next);
});
```

So basically my question is: is it safe to use the full request body as an input to the `model.create()` function (and `model.set()` and `model.build()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, before passing data to any persistence technology you should be validating the input to see if it is safe for your domain. So, even if this is safe from a SQL Injection Attack point-of-view, I'd still suggest doing the second way with an additional validation step before calling `models.Account.create` so that you are passing known values to the ORM, rather than whatever has come in the body of the HTTP request (which could be anything, not just what was on your page)

Comment: Sounds like a valid point in general (as you said). But in this case with this special ORM, validation functionality for the model is already in the ORM. Shouldn't all validation be done in the ORM? Keeping thin controllers is generally considered good practice.

Comment: If you want to look at it a different way, you are dealing with two end points that talk to external systems (what those are makes no difference). The data that comes in and goes out of those end points should be designed for those end points (which is not necessarily the same as what your system needs, or other end points need).

Comment: Sorry, that was quite an abstract response.